# How to use Redux and React navigation to make a global counter

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I am making a React-Native app in which I have a navigator from React Navigation and I also want to implement Redux. I am trying to create a global counter that updates based on an argument. 
Here is the actions:

```
export const setFlags = (value) => {
return {
    type: 'SETFLAGS',
    value
}
```

}

```
export const setNonFlags = (value) => {
    return {
        type: 'SETNONFLAGS',
        value
    }
}
```

Here is the reducer, because its two things that have identical functionality I thought one would work (I am new to Redux):

```
   const initialState = {
    flags:0,
    nonFlags:0,

}

const AllFlagReducer = (state = initialState, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){


        case 'SETFLAGS':
            return state.flags = state.flags + action.value
        case 'SETNONFLAGS':
            return state.nonFlags = state.nonFlags + action.value

    }
    return state
}

export default AllFlagReducer
```

And here is the button where I would like to send the local state of the "flag" and "nonFlag" to the redux global states. After which I reset the local states and move to the next screen.

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.resetButton}
            onPress= {
              // dispatch something like flags(in redux):this.state.flags
              // dispatch nonFlags(in redux): this.state.nonFlags
              () =>{this.resetAll();
              navigation.navigate('Specific Scams')

            }}>
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.
UPDATE 1:
The entire component:

```
class ScamTree extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    flags : 0,
    nonFlags: 0,
    qAnswered:0
  }
}
```

functions that might matter:

```
resetAll = () =>{
  this.setState({flags:0})
  this.setState({nonFlags:0})
  this.setState({qAnswered:0})

}
```

the button, (I did not make a separate component for just the button):

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.resetButton}
            onPress= {
              // dispatch something like flags:this.state.flags
              // dispatch nonFlags: this.state.nonFlags
              () =>{this.resetAll();store.dispatch({type:"SETFLAGS",value:5})
              navigation.navigate('Specific Scams')

            }}>

            <Text style={{paddingHorizontal:40}}>NEXT</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

the export to make React Navigation Work:

```
export default function(props) {
const navigation = useNavigation();

return <ScamTree {...props} navigation={navigation} />;
```

}

Comment: So what do you need help with? You have the actions, the reducer... assuming you've configured your redux store and provider you need now only connect the component and dispatch the actions with a value.

Comment: So if all of that is correct, would you mind showing how to create a component to accomplish this? I tried "useDispatch" and wrote a separate functional component but it did not work due to this being a class component.

Comment: Mind sharing the entire component code of the `TouchableOpacity`? It'd be simple then to show how to connect it to your store using the [`connect` HOC](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect).

Comment: @DrewReese I updated the post to show the class, functions, the touchableOpacity, and export, but I did not make a separate component for the button because it uses some local state in the class. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand a comment of yours in another answer, and the snippet of your question update, I believe you need to decorate *this* functional component:

```
export default function(props) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return <ScamTree {...props} navigation={navigation} />;
}
```

You want to decorate *this* component with the `connect` HOC to connect it to your redux store.

First I'd convert that function to a new `withNavigation` HOC:

```
const withNavigation = WrappedComponent => props => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return <WrappedComponent{...props} navigation={navigation} />;
};
withNavigation.displayName = `withNavigation(${WrappedComponent.displayName || 'Component'})`;
```

Now you can decorate `ScamTree` as follows:

```
export default withNavigation(ScamTree);
```

But now you also need to connect your action creators to your redux store, decorate it with `react-redux`'s [`connect`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) HOC:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setFlags,
  setNonFlags,
};

export default withNavigation(
  connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ScamTree),
);
```

*Note: I see it seems you store in local state some flag values, not sure if that is related, but you can map in initial state for this with a `mapStateToProps` as the first parameter for connect instead of null.*

By now you've probably noticed that each new HOC creates some *nesting*, and this will get worse with the more HOC's used. The solution is to use `redux`'s [`compose`](https://redux.js.org/api/compose/) HOC. That's right, it's not just for composing middleware for the store. It can compose all the decorators into a single HOC to wrap your exported component, or in other words, it flattens/eliminates the nesting.

> **[Tips](https://redux.js.org/api/compose/#tips)**
>
> All `compose` does is let you write deeply nested function
>   transformations without the rightward drift of the code. Don't give it
>   too much credit!

```
...
import { compose } from 'redux';
...

class ScamTree extends Component { ... }

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setFlags,
  setNonFlags,
};

export default compose(
  withNavigation,
  connect(null, mapDispatchToProps),
)(ScamTree);
```

**Note:** Your reducers need to always return ***new*** state object references and ***never*** mutate existing state. Also, although your returns do work correctly, the reducer pattern is to return unhandled action types in the default switch case:

```
const AllFlagReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'SETFLAGS':
        return { ...state, flags: state.flags + action.value };

    case 'SETNONFLAGS':
        return { ...state, nonFlags: state.nonFlags + action.value };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

In your .js class you have to bind your action like this

```
  import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
  import { connect } from 'react-redux';

  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.resetButton}
        onPress= {
          // dispatch something like flags(in redux):this.state.flags
          // dispatch nonFlags(in redux): this.state.nonFlags
          () =>{
          this.resetAll();
          this.props.commanAction.setFlags(your value);
          this.props.commanAction.setNonFlags(your value);
          navigation.navigate('Specific Scams')

        }}>

  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
      return {
         commanAction: bindActionCreators(commanAction, dispatch)
      };
   };

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Your .js className);
```

Other code are looks good.

Comment: Thank you, but with React navigation in class components I have to export the class like this: export default function(props) {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    
    return <STree {...props} navigation={navigation} />;
  }, So how would I connect as well?

Comment: The `mapDispatchToProps` within the `connect` HOC wraps (binds) each action in a call to dispatch *using* `bindActionCreators`, so the explicit use of  `bindActionCreators` is completely unnecessary. https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#object-shorthand-form

Answer (score 0):

In your reducer cases right now you writing new state over the whole state instead just in the fit place at state object, it can be written like

---

```
const AllFlagReducer = (state = initialState, action) =>{
 switch(action.type){
    case 'SETFLAGS':
        return { ...state, flags: state.flags + action.value }
    case 'SETNONFLAGS':
        return { ...state, nonFlags: state.nonFlags + action.value }
    default: return state
     }
    }
export default AllFlagReducer
```

---